# Get IndexSet in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

Getting the data like this:

```
@ObservedObject var meal: Meals
@ObservedObject var mealsController: CoreDataMealsController
```

where meal is the single current object I'm looking at.

I defined my delete function like this:

```
func deleteEntry(entry: Meals) {
        let mainC = CoreDataStack.shared.mainContext
        mainC.delete(entry)
        saveToPersistentStore() }

     func deleteEntry(at indexSet: IndexSet) {
         guard let index = Array(indexSet).first else { return }

         let entry = self.mealsData[index]

         deleteEntry(entry: entry)
     }
```

How can I get the IndexSet of my current object `meal` so I can pass it to the function?

Comment: Would you show code where is your array of meals and in which place do you want to delete one?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you what to make a swipe delete in table . A SwiftUI List provides you with an IndexSet of deletions when you swipe to delete an object in the list. Iterate over the IndexSet with forEach.

Check this might help you.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/9335365-core-data-with-swiftui-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: If I wanted a swap delete I could use a List. That's not what I want or I'm asking